# SQL Subquery in join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am modifying an existing SQL query . The issue is that I want to add a description from a table to the existing data . I added a subquery as shown in the figure but it seems to change my return dataset . can anyonple please suggest how to get correct data using a subquery ?

```
SELECT TOP 100
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LTRIM(VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL) ASC, LTRIM(VW_POLINDEX.POLNUM) ASC, LTRIM(VW_POLINDEX.MODULE) ASC ) AS RowNum
       ,VW_POLINDEX.POLNUM
       ,VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL
       ,VW_POLINDEX.MODULE
       ,
        --Subquery: 1 This subquery will fetch the description based on the pol details 
        ( SELECT TOP 1
                    reasonamendedCd
          FROM      SHPolicyAmendmentHistory SH
          WHERE     SH.PolicyNbr = VW_POLINDEX.POLNUM
                    AND SH.PolicySymbolCd = VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL
                    AND SH.PolicyModuleNbr = Module
          ORDER BY  amendmentnbr DESC
        ) AS POLSECRIPTION
       ,VW_POLINDEX.CANCELLD
FROM    VW_POLINDEX WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN LINE_OF_BUS_LIT WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON VW_POLINDEX.LOB = LINE_OF_BUS_LIT.LOB_CD
        INNER JOIN POL_STATUS_LIT WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON VW_POLINDEX.TYPEACT = POL_STATUS_LIT.POL_STATUS_CD
WHERE   ( CASE VW_POLINDEX.MODULE
            WHEN 0 THEN VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL + '0'
            ELSE VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL + '1'
          END ) NOT IN ( 'RJD1', 'RJH1' )
        AND VW_POLINDEX.LOB = 'HP'
```

**Current output:**

```
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|RowNum|POLNUM |SYMBOL|MODULE|POLSECRIPTION|CANCELLD |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|3     |0040026|CCS   |2     |<NULL>       |9/12/2006|
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+ 
|4     |0040026|CCS   |3     |<NULL>       |9/12/2010|
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|2     |0040026|CCS   |1     |<NULL>       |9/12/2006|
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+ 
|7     |2000010|CCS   |2     |XM           |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|8     |2000010|CCS   |3     |CPP          |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|12    |2000025|CCS   |0     |RN           |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|16    |2000025|CCS   |4     |RN           |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|6     |2000010|CCS   |1     |IC           |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|20    |2000029|CCS   |1     |RN           |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|10    |2000010|CCS   |5     |CM           |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|11    |2000010|CCS   |6     |Z            |7/28/2013|
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|24    |2000029|CCS   |5     |RN           |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|14    |2000025|CCS   |2     |RN           |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
```

**Expected output**
 (some row is missing in the prev output and also non sorted after adding subquery) :

```
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|RowNum|POLNUM |SYMBOL|MODULE|POLSECRIPTION|CANCELLD |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|1     |0040026|CCS   |0     |test         |9/12/2006|
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|2     |0040026|CCS   |1     |test         |9/12/2006|
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|3     |0040026|CCS   |2     |test         |9/12/2006|
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|4     |0040026|CCS   |3     |test         |9/12/2010|
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|5     |2000010|CCS   |0     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|6     |2000010|CCS   |1     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|7     |2000010|CCS   |2     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|8     |2000010|CCS   |3     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|9     |2000010|CCS   |4     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|10    |2000010|CCS   |5     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|11    |2000010|CCS   |6     |test         |7/28/2013|
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|12    |2000025|CCS   |0     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|13    |2000025|CCS   |1     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|14    |2000025|CCS   |2     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|15    |2000025|CCS   |3     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
|16    |2000025|CCS   |4     |test         |1/1/1753 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the syntax is SQL Server.

Comment: The output is not sorted because you're not sorting it and so it can be returned any which way the `SQL SERVER` wishes. Add a `ORDER BY` clause. And are you really sure you want `NOLOCK` in there?

Comment: Yeah , output can be sorted , but adding the subquery gives me incorrect data , some rows are missing after sorting as well . Also I need to get the top 1 from SHPolicyAmendmentHistory  based on amend date so not sure if join would help as it brings all the columns in SHPolicyAmendmentHistory

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use that description table in INNER JOIN? LIKE

```
SELECT TOP 100
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LTRIM(VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL) ASC, LTRIM(VW_POLINDEX.POLNUM) ASC, LTRIM(VW_POLINDEX.MODULE) ASC ) AS RowNum
       ,VW_POLINDEX.POLNUM
       ,VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL
       ,VW_POLINDEX.MODULE
       ,VW_POLINDEX.CANCELLD
       ,SH.reasonamendedCd
FROM    VW_POLINDEX WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN LINE_OF_BUS_LIT WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON VW_POLINDEX.LOB = LINE_OF_BUS_LIT.LOB_CD
        INNER JOIN POL_STATUS_LIT WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON VW_POLINDEX.TYPEACT = POL_STATUS_LIT.POL_STATUS_CD
        INNER JOIN SHPolicyAmendmentHistory SH ON SH.PolicyNbr = VW_POLINDEX.POLNUM
                                                  AND SH.PolicySymbolCd = VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL
                                                  AND SH.PolicyModuleNbr = Module
WHERE   ( CASE VW_POLINDEX.MODULE
            WHEN 0 THEN VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL + '0'
            ELSE VW_POLINDEX.SYMBOL + '1'
          END ) NOT IN ( 'RJD1', 'RJH1' )
        AND VW_POLINDEX.LOB = 'HP'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response .
The SHPolicyAmendmentHistory can return multiple columns . I need the top 1 based on the order by amendmentnbr desc